# Import datasets in which some columns have strings that contain spaces

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

I have a dataset that looks like the one below:

```
 ID          Message     
  1                .
  2                .
  3     Click_screen
  4     Blank screen
  5                .
  6                .
  7                .
```

The actual dataset has 48 columns and 50,000 rows.

Importing this dataset with **read.table()** is problematic because of the string "Blank screen", which has a space between the two sub-strings. For example, I got an error message like:

```
  Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
     line 4 did not have 48 elements
```

I wonder if there is any way to circumvent this problem in R rather than change the original dataset in Excel.

EDIT: Just to add, I tried to set fill to TRUE, and I got an error message below:

```
 Error in read.table(file.choose(), header = T, fill = T) : 
   duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

Comment: did you try to read with option fill =TRUE ?

Comment: It gave me the following error message: 
Error in read.table(file.choose(), header = T, fill = T) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Comment: try without header , hedaer = F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is space-separated (as opposed to tab-separted), you might want read.fwf, along with a vector of field widths.
If the file is tab-separated, you might want read.table(sep='\t',...).

Comment: sep="\t" did the trick in conjunction with agstudy's suggestion of fill=TRUE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your local separator but try this

```
read.table(fileName,fill=TRUE,header=FALSE,sep =';')
```